# ChangeNotifierProvider vs ChangeNotifierProvider.value

Tags: flutter, frameworks, provider, state-management

I am quite new to this framework and working on state management using provider package where I come across `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`, but I am unable to distinguish their use case.

I had used `ChangeNotifierProvider` in place of `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`, but it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Let's take this in steps.

### What is ChangeNotifier?

A class that extends `ChangeNotifier` can call `notifyListeners()` any time data in that class has been updated and you want to let a listener know about that update. This is often done in a view model to notify the UI to rebuild the layout based on the new data.

Here is an example:

```
class MyChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  void increment() {
    _counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I wrote more about this in [A beginner’s guide to architecting a Flutter app](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-beginners-guide-to-architecting-a-flutter-app-1e9053211a74).

### What is ChangeNotifierProvider?

`ChangeNotifierProvider` is one of [many types of providers](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd) in the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). If you already have a ChangeNotifier class (like the one above), then you can use `ChangeNotifierProvider` to provide it to the place you need it in the UI layout.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyChangeNotifier>(        // define it
      create: (context) => MyChangeNotifier(),              // create it
      child: MaterialApp(
        ...

          child: Consumer<MyChangeNotifier>(                // get it
            builder: (context, myChangeNotifier, child) {
              ...
                  myChangeNotifier.increment();             // use it
```

Note in particular that a new instance of the MyChangeNotifier class was created in this line:

```
create: (context) => MyChangeNotifier(),
```

This is done one time when the widget is first built, and not on subsequent rebuilds.

### What is ChangeNotifierProvider.value for then?

Use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` if you have already created an instance of the `ChangeNotifier` class. This type of situation might happen if you had initialized your `ChangeNotifier` class in the `initState()` method of your `StatefulWidget`'s `State` class.

In that case, you wouldn't want to create a whole new instance of your `ChangeNotifier` because you would be wasting any initialization work that you had already done. Using the `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` constructor allows you to provide your pre-created `ChangeNotifier` value.

```
class _MyWidgeState extends State<MyWidge> {

  MyChangeNotifier myChangeNotifier;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myChangeNotifier = MyChangeNotifier();
    myChangeNotifier.doSomeInitializationWork();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyChangeNotifier>.value(
      value: myChangeNotifier,                           // <-- important part
      child: ...
```

Take special note that there isn't a `create` parameter here, but a `value` parameter. That's where you pass in your `ChangeNotifier` class instance. Again, don't try to create a new instance there.

You can also find the usage of `ChangeNotifierProvider` and `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` described in the official docs: https://pub.dev/packages/provider#exposing-a-value

Comment: 1. when you use `ChangeNotifierProvider` you can use the existing changeNotifier instance (for example created in your initState()) in `create` method: `ChangeNotifierProvider(create(_)=> myChangeNotifier)`   2. If you're using `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` you must manually dispose your changeNotifier.

Answer (score 9):

Does the official documentation help?

> **DO** use ChangeNotifierProvider.value to provider an existing `ChangeNotifier`:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: variable,
  child: ...
)
```

> **DON'T** reuse an existing `ChangeNotifier` using the default constructor.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  builder: (_) => variable,   
  child: ... 
)
```

Also check out this [Github issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/170) from the author about this.

Comment: note: you *can* use an existing changeNotifier in the *create* method ChangeNotifierProvider(create(_) => variable)

Answer (score 5):

**ValueNotifier and ChangeNotifier are closely related.**

> In fact, ValueNotifier is a subclass of ChangeNotifier that implements
>   ValueListenable.

This is the implementation of ValueNotifier in the Flutter SDK:

```
/// A [ChangeNotifier] that holds a single value.
///
/// When [value] is replaced with something that is not equal to the old
/// value as evaluated by the equality operator ==, this class notifies its
/// listeners.
class ValueNotifier<T> extends ChangeNotifier implements ValueListenable<T> {
  /// Creates a [ChangeNotifier] that wraps this value.
  ValueNotifier(this._value);

  /// The current value stored in this notifier.
  ///
  /// When the value is replaced with something that is not equal to the old
  /// value as evaluated by the equality operator ==, this class notifies its
  /// listeners.
  @override
  T get value => _value;
  T _value;
  set value(T newValue) {
    if (_value == newValue)
      return;
    _value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '${describeIdentity(this)}($value)';
}
```

**So, when should we use ValueNotifier vs ChangeNotifier?**

> Use ValueNotifier if you need widgets to rebuild when a simple value
>   changes. Use ChangeNotifier if you want more control on when
>   notifyListeners() is called.

Comment: A digressive answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

Is an important difference between ChangeNotifierProvider.value and with the create function. When you're using Provider in a single list or grid item, Flatter removes items when they leave the screen and re adds them when they reentered the screen in such situations what actually happens is that the widget itself is reused by Flutter and just the data that's attached to it changes. So Flatter recycles the same widget it doesn't destroy it 
and recreate it. when we are using Provider with the create function.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => new MyChangeNotifier(),
  child: ...
)
```

☝☝☝ here which is content changes over time and our provider won't pick us up.

In a single list or grid item, we should use Provider dot value.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: new MyChangeNotifier(),
  child: ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the ChangeNotifierProvider with builder(Provider v3) or create(Provider v4) parameter is a disposing provider, this provider owns the state source and manages its lifetime. The value provider only references the state source but does not manage its lifetime.
In disposing providers, the builder or create parameter provides a function for creating the state source. In value providers there is a value parameter which takes a reference to the state source and you are responsible for creating and disposing the state source as needed.