# Why my list is not rebuild after rearanging items

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider

This is toy app using Flutter and Provider package. My goals are simple:
- `OuterProvider` have data which is used to build a list (`ListView.builder`)
- `Outer provider` have `Shuffle` button which shuffle inner list
- Inner Widgets (`Rows`) uses `InnerProvider` to proceed with changing data randomly

When i click on `InnerWidget` - provider updates data correctly 
But when I shuffle data, even if data is shuffled. Build method is run but my widgets list is not affected….

Here is sample code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class InnerProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pid;
  InnerProvider(this.pid);

  get id => pid;

  set id(int i) {
    pid = i;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class OuterProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List _data = [
    InnerProvider(1),
    InnerProvider(3),
    InnerProvider(4),
    InnerProvider(5),
  ];

  get data => _data;

  addToData(var item) {
    data.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  reShuffle() {
    data.shuffle();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changeId(var i) {

    var dtIndex = _data.indexOf(i);
    _data[dtIndex].id = Random().nextInt(99);
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<OuterProvider>(
        create: (_) => OuterProvider(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Why this does not work?'),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List outerData;

  void reShuffleData() {
    Provider.of<OuterProvider>(context).reShuffle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    outerData = Provider.of<OuterProvider>(context, listen: true).data;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: outerData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                return ChangeNotifierProvider<InnerProvider>(
                    create: (_) => outerData[i], child: InnerChild());
              })),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: reShuffleData,
        tooltip: 'Shuffle',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerChild extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var prov = Provider.of<InnerProvider>(context);
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Provider.of<OuterProvider>(context).changeId(prov);
          },
          child: Text(
            Provider.of<InnerProvider>(context).id.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          )),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the working code. You were consuming the default values and were not consuming the change. Please refer the code below.

***Edited***

You should use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` for this use-case instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider`. [***Difference***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335980/changenotifierprovider-vs-changenotifierprovider-value)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class InnerProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pid;
  InnerProvider(this.pid);

  get id => pid;

  set id(int i) {
    pid = i;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class OuterProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List _data = [
    InnerProvider(1),
    InnerProvider(3),
    InnerProvider(4),
    InnerProvider(5),
  ];

  get data => _data;

  addToData(var item) {
    data.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  reShuffle() {
    data.shuffle();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  changeId(var i) {

    var dtIndex = _data.indexOf(i);
    _data[dtIndex].id = Random().nextInt(99);
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<OuterProvider>(
        create: (_) => OuterProvider(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Why this does not work?'),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List outerData;

  void reShuffleData() {
    Provider.of<OuterProvider>(context).reShuffle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    outerData = Provider.of<OuterProvider>(context, listen: true).data;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: outerData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                return  ChangeNotifierProvider<InnerProvider>.value(
                  value: outerData[i],
                  child: InnerChild(),
                );
              })),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: reShuffleData,
        tooltip: 'Shuffle',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerChild extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var prov = Provider.of<InnerProvider>(context);
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Provider.of<OuterProvider>(context).changeId(prov);
          },
          child: Text(
            Provider.of<InnerProvider>(context).id.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          )),
    ]);
  }
}
```