# Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this MyApp Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I am building a sample app for signup and login,
the first page shows is mobile authentication using firebase, and after successful authentication, I fetch uid from firebase and try to match with documenteID of my cloud firestore collection('user'). If it gives me null then I want to show SignupScreen(), otherwise, show HomeScreen().

So it is my simple logic but I don't know this type of error occurred,

I tried some different code also which is

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => User(),
    ),
```

but it still shows error.

Here is my code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phone_auth_example/homePage.dart';
import 'package:phone_auth_example/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './signUpPage.dart';
import './user.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    var checkUser = false;
    void isNewUser() async {
      final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
      final uid = user.uid;
      Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).isUserNew(uid);
      checkUser = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).checkUser;
    }

    isNewUser();

    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: User(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: StreamBuilder(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
              if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
                if (checkUser) {
                  return SignupScreen();
                } else {
                  return HomePage();
                }
              } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return LoginPage();
            },
          ),
          routes: {
            SignupScreen.routeName: (ctx) => SignupScreen(),
          },
        ),);
  }
}
```

**user.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

enum UserType {
  Member,
  HigherAuthority,
  SecurityGuard,
}

enum UserStatus {
  Owner,
  Renter,
}

enum OccupancyStatus {
  CurrentlyResiding,
  EmptyHouse,
}

class User with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final UserType userType;
  final String mobileNumber;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String houseNumberId;
  final UserStatus userStatus;
  final OccupancyStatus occupancyStatus;

  User({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.userType,
    @required this.mobileNumber,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.email,
    @required this.password,
    @required this.houseNumberId,
    @required this.userStatus,
    @required this.occupancyStatus,
  });

  bool checkUser;

  Future<void> isUserNew(String userId) async {
    // Get data from firestore
    DocumentSnapshot user =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(userId).get();

    //print(variable.data == null);

    // Check whether userId is in collection or not
    checkUser = (user.data == null) ? true : false;
  }
}
```

First, it's open LoginPage() that is works perfectly, and after that its direct goto HomePage() instead of signupPage(), no matter the uid match or not, so that is a problem and it shows error like...

**ERROR**

````
I/Choreographer(10505): Skipped 246 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/flutter (10505): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this MyApp Widget
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505): This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
E/flutter (10505): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
E/flutter (10505):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505):   Make sure that MyApp is under your MultiProvider/Provider<User>.
E/flutter (10505):   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505):   For example, instead of:
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505):   ```
E/flutter (10505):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
E/flutter (10505):     return Provider<Example>(
E/flutter (10505):       create: (_) => Example(),
E/flutter (10505):       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
E/flutter (10505):       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
E/flutter (10505):       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
E/flutter (10505):     ),
E/flutter (10505):   }
E/flutter (10505):   ```
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505):   consider using `builder` like so:
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505):   ```
E/flutter (10505):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
E/flutter (10505):     return Provider<Example>(
E/flutter (10505):       create: (_) => Example(),
E/flutter (10505):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
E/flutter (10505):       builder: (context) {
E/flutter (10505):         // No longer throws
E/flutter (10505):         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
E/flutter (10505):       }
E/flutter (10505):     ),
E/flutter (10505):   }
E/flutter (10505):   ```
E/flutter (10505):
E/flutter (10505): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
````

Comment: But from the error log, you've be provided the solution .... am I the only one seeing this ?

Comment: can you explain please where is the solution and how to implement that one?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to call `Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).checkUser` while no provider has been given in the context yet (since you use `MultiProvider` lower down your tree).

You should move up the MultiProvider. Here is an example of an implementation:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phone_auth_example/homePage.dart';
import 'package:phone_auth_example/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './signUpPage.dart';
import './user.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<User>(
            create: (context) => User(),
          ),
        ],
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

          var checkUser = false;
          void isNewUser() async {
            final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
            final uid = user.uid;
            Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).isUserNew(uid);
            checkUser = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).checkUser;
          }

          isNewUser();

          return child;
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: StreamBuilder(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
              if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
                if (checkUser) {
                  return SignupScreen();
                } else {
                  return HomePage();
                }
              } else if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return LoginPage();
            },
          ),
          routes: {
            SignupScreen.routeName: (ctx) => SignupScreen(),
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore there are 2 misuse of ChangeNotifier:

1 The User class should **extend** ChangeNotifier.

Replace

```
class User with ChangeNotifier
```

With

```
class User extends ChangeNotifier
```

2 ChangeNotifierProvider.value should be used if you already created an instance of the ChangeNotifier (User in your case): [here is a great explaination of the use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861315/5990125). Since you did not, your should use ChangeNotifierProvider like this:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<User>(
      create: (context) => User(),
      child: ...
)
```

Comment: I tried whatever you mentioned in the answer but still, it is showing the same error.
Can you please check once again?

Comment: Can you try this?

Comment: Now it's showing like this...

Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(26592): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(26592): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

I/Choreographer(26592): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/ResourceType(26592): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
V/NativeCrypto(26592): Registering

Comment: Try "flutter clean" ?