# ChangeNotifierProvider: can its created ChangeNotifier get recreated?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management

Can a `ChangeNotifierProvider`'s `ChangeNotifier` get recreated?

My impression from reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335980/changenotifierprovider-vs-changenotifierprovider-value) is that when a `ChangeNotifierProvider` does `create: (context) => SomeChangeNotifier()`, `SomeChangeNotifier` is guaranteed to never be recreated:

> This is done one time when the widget is first built, and not on subsequent rebuilds.

This is what I would hope and expect. However, according to the [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider):

> ChangeNotifierProvider is smart enough not to rebuild [its ChangeNotifier] unless absolutely necessary.

Note the "unless absolutely necessary" part, which suggests that the `ChangeNotifier` *can* be recreated.

Comment: If you close your app and then open up again, it's ***absolutely necessary*** to recreate, I guess :-) Or when you navigate to another screen and after that navigate back.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to understand is that the lifecycle of a `ChangeNotifier` depends on the lifecycle of what you are providing.

for example, if you want the state of a view to be alive all the while the app is not closed, then you would make it global and declare it above the `MaterialApp`.

But sometimes you might want the recreate the state of a particular view for example,

if the views are so,  1->2->3  then 3rd view might want to be reset, and this time you provide it only above the route which resets the state and rebuilds when accessed again.

I believe this is what

> ChangeNotifierProvider is smart enough not to rebuild [its ChangeNotifier] unless absolutely necessary.

means

You could also manually call dispose on it whenever you want even if its provided globally.